# jQuery code messing up rest of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

This jQuery code as part of [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) messes up all the jQuery code below it, what's wrong please? (By messing up I mean I don't believe code below fires.)

Very many thanks for your help, and please let me know if you would like any further details.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('social-section-3'),
  handler: function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $('.social-bg-tennis-video').get(0).pause();
          $('.social-bg-events-video').get(0).play();
      }
      if (direction === 'up') {
          $('.social-bg-tennis-video').get(0).play();
          $('.social-bg-events-video').get(0).pause();
      }
  }
});

var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('home-section-5'),
  handler: function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $('.home-bg-social-video').get(0).play();
      }
      if (direction === 'up') {
          $('.home-bg-social-video').get(0).pause();
      }
  }
});

var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('coaching-section-3'),
  handler: function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $('.coaching-bg-private-video').get(0).pause();
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).play();
      }
      if (direction === 'up') {
          $('.coaching-bg-private-video').get(0).play();
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).pause();
      }
  }
});
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('coaching-section-4'),
  handler: function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).pause();
          $('.coaching-bg-mini-video').get(0).play();
      }
      if (direction === 'up') {
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).play();
         $('.coaching-bg-mini-video').get(0).pause();
      }
  }
});
```

UPDATE

I Have found that I can add as many…

```
var waypoint_coachingsection3 = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementsByClassName('coaching-section-3'),
  handler: function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $('.coaching-bg-private-video').get(0).pause();
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).play();
      }
      if (direction === 'up') {
          $('.coaching-bg-private-video').get(0).play();
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).pause();
      }
  }
});
```

…as I like and the code the Waypoints code works, although any unrelated jQuery below or above this code fails.

I also found if I add other of these code blocks for elements on other pages, the Waypoint code blocks for the other pages below the top code fail!

Also, I found this as the only (related) console error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘top’ of undefined – jquery.waypoints.min.js:7

Comment: Looks like that code declares and initializes the same variable four times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pointy. Would that mean just changing 'waypoint' to anything unique? I have tried this but with no luck so far - and I guess you don't change 'Waypoint' as this referrers to the global Waypoint class. Do you know please?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what sort of problem  that'd cause, but it's just a little odd. If a reference to a Waypoint instance doesn't have to be saved in order for the library to work, then there's not much point doing *any* assignment. On the other hand, if it does, then yes you'd want to use different variable names or else put all the instances in an array.

Comment: Hmm i Know what you mean, but sadly it hasn't worked making them unique. Any other ideas please?

Comment: It looks like the 'element' property of the options is meant to be a singular DOM element (at least, that's what it looks like in the documentation). getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList (which is similar to an array) and wouldn't have the same properties for it to use. Try setting up the waypoints using singular elements and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using a different method of calling Waypoints which worked for my situation, eg.:

```
var waypoints = $('.coaching-section-3').waypoint({
  handler: function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'down') {
          $('.coaching-bg-private-video').get(0).pause();
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).play();
      }
      if (direction === 'up') {
          $('.coaching-bg-private-video').get(0).play();
          $('.coaching-bg-junior-video').get(0).pause();
      }
  },
  offset: '30%'
})
```

Thanks for everyone's help.